# Extract application database from android device through adb

Tags: android, database, adb

How can I extract the database of an application from an android device through an adb shell command?

Comment: Asked 1000 times on here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Databases are stored in files, mostly on internal storage, in App's data directory like :

```
/data/data/com.example.myapp/mydb
```

so you can do

```
adb pull /data/data/com.example.myapp/mydb
```

Then you can use [some software](http://sqliteman.com/) to open that file, and work with data base. To place it back:

```
adb push <new file> /data/data/com.example.myapp/mydb
```

Answer (score 9):

If you have neither SD card  nor root on your device, just use adb shell.

```
$ adb shell
$ run-as com.your.package cat /data/data/com.your.package/databases/your_db > /storage/sdcard0/Download/your.db
```

Then use DDMS to pull file out.

Comment: I am certain this will only work if your package has debuggable set to true.

Comment: Just note that the last path may be different for you. Its /sdcard/Download/your.db on my Nexus 5

Comment: solved it ty ty

Answer (score 0):

As of Android 9, the `Download` directory has moved to `/storage/emulated/0/Download/`. I combined [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21424698/15170120) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471780/retrieve-database-or-any-other-file-from-the-internal-storage-using-run-as?noredirect=1&lq=1) with the new location to pull the database file:

1. `run-as com.packagename`
2. `cp /data/data/com.packagename/databases/databaseName.db databaseNameNewFile.db`
3. `cp databaseNameNewFile.db /storage/emulated/0/Download`

Then I enabled file transfer on the phone, opened it with File Explorer, went to Internal Storage/Download, found the database file, and copied it to my computer.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK you can fetch databases only from Android Emulator, not from real device (unless the device is rooted).
To do so, simply go to DDMS --> File Explorer --> data --> data --> your package name -- > databases

Your database should be inside databases folder

Once you select your database, you will see two icons on the upper tab wherein you can push or pull the database.

Answer (score -1):

I dont think u can extract extract database from device, but yes you can extract it from emulator from DDMS > File Explorer > data > data > package  > databases